# CSS3 How to clear the underline from a:-webkit-any-link

Tags: html, css

I will just describe my problem in the pic. 
https://snag.gy/jIilU4.jpg
Is there any solution to take off this text-decoration? I tried to add text-decoration: none; but it's doesn't work for me. I guess its pretty easy to explain but i'm pretty new with CSS.

```
 body {
    background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.logo img:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: box;
    flex-align: center;
    flex-pack: center;
}

#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

There is a HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>

    <title>How to align the items of the flexible element</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Highscores</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Premium</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="/" title="Medivia Online">
            <img src="css/img/medivia.png" alt="Medivia Logo">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;" id="slideshow">

        <div>
            <img src="css/img/chimera.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="css/img/queens_follower.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="css/img/player_killing.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="css/img/general.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="css/img/hydra.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="css/img/ogre_death.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="css/img/raid.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="css/img/icenhaal.png">
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function () {
            $('#slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow');
        }, 3000);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post the whole code (the html is missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with css selector. You dont mention  the parent class or Id before ul li and a tag which you set for menu.  So those tags effect all the ul,li , a on your html page. [Read This](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
 body {
background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: top;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-size: cover;
}

.menu ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

.menu li {
float: left;
}

.menu li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.logo {
text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
height: auto;
width: auto;
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-property: transform;
}

.logo img:hover {
transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.logo a {
text-decoration: none;
}

#slideshow {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
width: 240px;
height: 240px;
padding: 10px;
display: box;
flex-align: center;
flex-pack: center;
}

#slideshow > div {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>

<title>How to align the items of the flexible element</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Library</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Download</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Highscores</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Premium</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="logo">
    <a href="/" title="Medivia Online">
        <img src="css/img/medivia.png" alt="Medivia Logo">
    </a>
</div>

<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;" id="slideshow">

    <div>
        <img src="css/img/chimera.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="css/img/queens_follower.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="css/img/player_killing.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="css/img/general.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="css/img/hydra.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="css/img/ogre_death.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="css/img/raid.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="css/img/icenhaal.png">
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, 3000);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Lets see which gets chosen...:D

Comment: @Gezzasa do you think i'm waiting for  a green tick. I just giving an answer. Now moving to another question :)

Comment: Well, I tried to target .logo a but only menu div has changed.

Comment: @serengeti why menu div will change.. can you add your html part on your question?

Comment: Well i dont know how it happened. But  after changing target now there is an additional option https://snag.gy/WcDhsT.jpg

Comment: Well, I should post whole css code, I think this was a problem: li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
That was a part of menu, deleting it solved my problem.

Comment: @serengeti its coming from your style.css please add whole css on question. maybe overwrite issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry i should post whole code at first. Thanks

Comment: .menu  a:hover:not(.active)  {background:red; } that shoud be like this for menu

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/fh8a55up/2/ ] no problem . CSS selector problem. You if you dont set the parent class or id for those ul,li,a and img tag then all those tags are effected on that page. On fiddle check that css section. also update my answer

Comment: Yeah, well i totally forgot about this previous hover. Thanks and sorry again for bad description.

Answer (score 2):

You're targeting the div and not the link (a tag).

```
.logo a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried to target .logo a but only menu div has changed.

Comment: I'm not sure how the menu got targeted when you specified '.logo a'. I'm either missing something or your CSS markup is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The css selection is wrong. The hyperlinks are the "a" tags so if you want it removed from the whole page not just one section use a { ... } or if it's one particular section for example .logo a { ... } .